# How do I correctly access this base class variable from the derived classes' constructors?

Tags: c++, derived-class

I'm writing a program that's intended to take multiple baked goods and print them out with varying prices based on the makeup of the item. The price increases as certain things are added like type of frosting or number of layers.

For some reason, the program doesn't accept any modification to the price variable unless it's declared explicitly in the constructor. I'd love some help with this, as I clearly don't understand it.

```
BakedGood::BakedGood() { // Base Class
    price = 0.0;
    frostingPrice = 0.0;
    pricePerLayer = 0.0;
}
BakedGood::BakedGood(double basePrice) {
    price = basePrice;
}
string BakedGood::ToString() { 
    return "($" + to_string(price) + ")";
}
```

```
// Cake class, derived from BakedGood class
Cake::Cake(string cakeFlavor, string frostingFlvr, double basePrice) : BakedGood(basePrice) {
    this->cakeFlavor = cakeFlavor;
    this->frostingFlvr = frostingFlvr;
}
```

```
CupCake::CupCake(string typeCupcake, string typeFrosting, string colorSpkl) 
     : Cake(typeCupcake, typeFrosting, basePrice) {  // Cupcake class, derived from Cake
    cakeFlavor = typeCupcake;
    frostingFlvr = typeFrosting;
    sprinkleColor = colorSpkl;
    if (frostingFlvr == "cream-cheese") {
        basePrice = 2.15;      // Price doesn't pass through
    }
    else {
        basePrice = 1.95;
    }
}
string CupCake::ToString() {
    string cupcakeOrder;
    cupcakeOrder = cakeFlavor + " cupcake with " + frostingFlvr + " frosting and " + sprinkleColor +
        " sprinkles " + BakedGood::ToString();
    return cupcakeOrder;
}
```

```
LayerCake::LayerCake(string typeCake, string typeFrost, int amntLayers) 
      : Cake(typeCake, typeFrost, basePrice) {  // Layercake class, derived from Cake
    cakeFlavor = typeCake;
    frostingFlvr = typeFrost;
    numLayers = amntLayers;
    if (frostingFlvr == "cream-cheese") {
        if (numLayers > 1) {
            basePrice = 9.0 + (numLayers) + ((numLayers - 1) * 3.0);
        }
        else {
            basePrice = 9.0 + (numLayers);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (numLayers > 1) {
            basePrice = 9.0 + ((numLayers - 1) * 3.0);
        }
        else {
            basePrice = 9.0;
        }
    }
}
string LayerCake::ToString() {
     ...
}
```

Ex. my output:
2-layer Chocolate cake with vanilla frosting ($0.000000)
3-layer Spice cake with cream-cheese frosting ($0.000000)
Yellow cupcake with cream-cheese frosting and red sprinkles ($0.000000)
Chocolate cupcake with vanilla frosting and blue sprinkles ($0.000000)

Solution output:
*2-layer Chocolate cake with vanilla frosting ($12.000000)*
*3-layer Spice cake with cream-cheese frosting ($18.000000)*
*Yellow cupcake with cream-cheese frosting and red sprinkles ($2.150000)*
*Chocolate cupcake with vanilla frosting and blue sprinkles ($1.950000)*

I'm sorry for so much code, I'm not sure at which part I need to fix. Also, basePrice isn't declared in Cupcake or Layercake, but it is declared as a protected variable in both Bakedgood and Cake.

Comment: Is the base variable `price`, or is that a typo? Also, what is `basePrice` when `CupCake` and `LayerCake` refer to it as they invoke their base constructor? It would definitely help to see the relevant parts of the data structure.

Comment: Consider changing your design approach. Why would you need inheritence for your task?